# Laravel 4: Fluent changes?

Tags: laravel, laravel-4

I read that Laravel 4 is not going to change much on the surface, saying that much of the old code would be compatible.

I try to use Fluent's `insert_get_id` like it says in the [docs](http://laravel.com/docs/database/fluent#insert), but the function doesn't exist.

Am I doing it wrong? If not, are there more changes in Fluent and / or Eloquent?

Comment: Check [four.laravel.com](http://four.laravel.com) for documentation on Laravel 4.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Laravel 4 has been changed to become PSR-1 complaint and as such is now camelCased instead of snake_cased. Try changing to `insertGetId()`.

Comment: Oh no, not the camelCase. iCantReadWhatThisMethodIsSupposedToDo()!

Answer (score 0):

I believe functions went from underscores to camelCase... try insertGetId